# Preventing polygon symbology from rotating with data frame when switching between map sheets in map series?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-9.3, data-driven-pages

I am using ArcGis 9.3, Windows XP and want to know if it's possible to have symbology in my polygons not rotate with data frame when I switch between mapsheets in my map series?

I do NOT have MPSAtlas or PLTS. I DO have DS Mapbook installed.

Answer (score 3):

Use Cartographic Representations: Data needs to be in a Geodatabase.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Rotating_feature_representations

You can do it without Cartographic Representations but have less control on the feature/symbol.

Creating a marker from a picture graphic:
http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Creating_marker_symbols

Comment: Thanks - I tried it, but I don't have PLTS and it looks like I need it.

Comment: No need for PLTS - updated link